# Ready only access dynamically in entity framework UnitOfWork and DbContextFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on MVC project and I am using entity framework with Repository pattern approach.

Now I am wan to implement read only access to application. So is there any generic way I can implement this dynamically based upon logged user rather than implementing on each page one by one.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by logged in user, or do you mean based on a user group?

Comment: yes based upon logged in user group/access/write

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/730841/asp-net-mvc-identity-implementing-group-based